# HTTP2に対応しているのにデベロッパーツールで見るとキューイングが発生している理由

Tags: apache, wordpress, http2

はじめまして、現在Wordpressでサービスを運営しています。
Chromeデベロッパーツールを今まで使わずにページスピードインサイト頼りでサイトの速度まわりの改善をしていましたが、デベロッパーツールのネットワークの項目も見てみたらよくわからないことがあったので質問です。

### 困っていること

デベロッパーツールのネットワークでウォーターフォールの項目を見ると、色が白色、つまりはキューイングが発生しているリクエストが多数存在します。HTTP2であればブラウザからの最大同時接続数は6の制約がなくなり、もっとたくさんの同時接続数が許されることになります。
Protocolの項目を見るとhtとなっていてHTTP2で通信できているようです。
にも関わらず、キューイングが発生しているリクエストが画像周りで多数(30くらい)発生しています。
HTTP2であれば同時接続数はそこまで制約にならないはずなのにどうしてキューイングが発生してしまうのでしょうか？

### 質問概要

HTTP2で通信しているのに多数のリクエストでキューイングが発生している。原因が何なのかを知りたい。

### 補足

WebサーバーはApacheをつかっています。

Comment: > `Protocolの項目を見るとhtとなっていてHTTP2で通信できているようです。` とありますが `ht` ではなく `h2` では？

Comment: 暗号化されていなければ`h2c`ですね。

Comment: サーバに接続されているネットワークの帯域(通信速度)はどのぐあいあって、キューイングされている画像の大きさ(バイト数)と数は、CPUの能力はどのぐらいなのですか？